# How to embed a variable within a command within double quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, sqlite

I have the following command that I run in my shell

`sqlite3 db.db 'select * from myTable where myColumn = "foo"'`

and instead of foo I would like to substitute a variable COLUMN_NAME
and I would like to store the output of the whole aforementioned command  into a variable.
I am having trouble escaping double quotes correctly.

The following does not work

```
COLUMN_NAME="foo"
OUTPUT="$(sqlite3 db.db 'select * from myTable where myColumn = ""$(COLUMN_NAME)""')"
```

I get the following error `Error: unrecognized token: "$"`

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: FYI -- POSIX-specified convention reserves all-caps variable names for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; and reserves lowercase variable names for application use, guaranteeing that such names can be used without unintended consequences with respect to behavior of the shell itself or POSIX-defined builtin utilities. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: BTW, you can run `bash -x yourscript` to see how your commands are interpreted (ie. what's actually being invoked at execution time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
column_name="foo"
output="$(sqlite3 db.db 'select * from myTable where myColumn = "'"${column_name}"'" ')"
```

Let's break down `"'"${column_name}"'"`:

- The first `"`, because it's inside a single-quoted string, is literal -- part of the SQL.
- The second character, `'`, is syntactic -- closing the single-quoted context that was started with the quotes before `'select`, so we can enter a double-quoted context where variable expansions are honored.
- The third character, `"`, is syntactic -- entering a double-quoted context where variable expansions are honored.
- `${column_name}` is a variable expansion. (You could also just use `$column_name` without the curly braces). Contrast with `$(column_name)`, which runs `column_name` as a command and substitutes that command's output. *Note that none of these expansions would be honored in single quotes, which is why we entered a double-quoted context above*. (By contrast, an *unquoted* context could be split into multiple arguments to SQLite if the value being substituted contained spaces).
- The final `"'"` perform the third, second and first bullets points' items in reverse: Ending the syntactic quotes, reentering a single-quoted context, and then injecting a single `"`.
- ...and following this we have a lone single-quote, ending the single-quoted context in which we added the literal `"` just prior.

Comment: after searching and searching for an answer all over the webs this is the only place I saw the "'" solution mentioned. This should enshrined somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, string literals [should use single quotes](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).
This makes it easier:

```bash
output="$(sqlite3 db.db "select * from myTable where myColumn = '$column_value'")"
```

Comment: More immediately, `$column_value` wasn't being expanded inside the single-quoted string.

Comment: @chepner What are you talking about? In the shell, single quotes have no special meaning inside a double-quote-delimited string.

Comment: Quite right -- when I first saw the OP using double-quoted literals, I assumed that they were trying to find places where `myColumn`'s value matched the value of another column in their schema named `foo`. Since they claim that their original meets their needs, that may well *be* their actual intent (and indeed, hopefully it is -- that would make the variable being called `column_name` make sense, and imply that its set of possible values is bounded, making SQL injection less of an immediate concern).

Comment: @CL You (necessarily) switched the OP's single-quoted argument to `sqlite3` to a double-quoted argument.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape from the single quotes since it will block variable substitutions

check this example and apply to your command

```
foo=substituted; var="$(echo 'this is '"$foo"' here ')"; echo $var

this is substituted here
```